# Rename keys in grouped array to represent the date they are grouped by

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array that I have grouped by 1 minute, relative to the rest of the date, except for seconds. The problem now is that the keys of each group in the array (3 groups) are just named 0, 1, 2 etc. and I want them to be named to the date they represent which they have been grouped by already.

Like so:

```
[
  "Fri Jan 31 2020 14:58": [
    {
      "_id": "5e34326b1da7e21c04ec76e8",
      "message": "15",
      "room": "5e32c3f858f00d4ef5f9ab81",
      "createdAt": 1580479083,
      "user": "5e10e7a6a69a4a36e4169bdc",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e34327e1da7e21c04ec76e9",
      "message": "hello",
      "room": "5e32c3f858f00d4ef5f9ab81",
      "createdAt": 1580479102,
      "user": "5e10e7a6a69a4a36e4169bdc",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e34328c1da7e21c04ec76ea",
      "message": "156",
      "room": "5e32c3f858f00d4ef5f9ab81",
      "createdAt": 1580479116,
      "user": "5e10e7a6a69a4a36e4169bdc",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
]
```

See the code snippet, how can I achieve this?

```js
const messages = [{"_id":"5e34326b1da7e21c04ec76e8","message":"15","room":"5e32c3f858f00d4ef5f9ab81","createdAt":1580479083,"user":"5e10e7a6a69a4a36e4169bdc","__v":0},{"_id":"5e34327e1da7e21c04ec76e9","message":"hello","room":"5e32c3f858f00d4ef5f9ab81","createdAt":1580479102,"user":"5e10e7a6a69a4a36e4169bdc","__v":0},{"_id":"5e34328c1da7e21c04ec76ea","message":"156","room":"5e32c3f858f00d4ef5f9ab81","createdAt":1580479116,"user":"5e10e7a6a69a4a36e4169bdc","__v":0},{"_id":"5e344bbc97cbc523d46acfad","message":"Newer","room":"5e32c3f858f00d4ef5f9ab81","createdAt":1580485564,"user":"5e10e7a6a69a4a36e4169bdc","__v":0},{"_id":"5e344e3a744b240a5cf7c9b5","message":"Newest ","room":"5e32c3f858f00d4ef5f9ab81","createdAt":1580486202,"user":"5e10e7a6a69a4a36e4169bdc","__v":0},{"_id":"5e344e3e744b240a5cf7c9b6","message":"Newest 1","room":"5e32c3f858f00d4ef5f9ab81","createdAt":1580486206,"user":"5e10e7a6a69a4a36e4169bdc","__v":0}];

const sortByDate = _.chain(messages)
 .groupBy(m => {
  const d = new Date(m.createdAt * 1000);
  console.log(d);
  
  return Math.floor(+(d) / (1000*60));
 })
 .sortBy((v, k) => { return k; })
 .value();

console.log(sortByDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Can you show us how your result should look like?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier yes, see the question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it with just `_.groupBy` and momentjs.

```
const sortByMinute = _.groupBy(messages, function (date) {
  return moment(date.createdAt*1000).startOf("minute").format();
});
```

It groups them by minute and the returned object is named accordingly!

Answer (score -1):

You could achieve that as this:

```
messages.map((message) => {
    d = new Date(message.createdAt);
    d.setMinutes(0);
    d.setSeconds(0);
    arr.push({[d]:message});
});
```

Hope it helps :)